# Email : Floating tables not going to the next line

Tags: html, email

I am stuck with the attached e-mail HTML file as it does not render properly in thunderbird, sometimes in AOL, outlook, etc... (depending on the browser).

What I was trying to do here was to display a number of profiles for a dating website. All the emails I send are responsive so I wanted it to behave this way :
- 580px wide email : 4 profiles
- Tablet version : 3 profiles
- Mobile version : 2 profiles

To achieve this, I created a table (which width will vary according to the device it's read on) and inside I put 8 small tables, expecting that when the border of the larger table is there, the next mini table would start a next line. But unfortunately it is only the case on some desktop clients & webmails, but not all of them.

Can you think of a solution to make this responsive friendly ?

Thanks in advance !

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="SayDating" content="True" />

    <title>E-mail</title>

    <style type="text/css">
      .ReadMsgBody {width: 100%; background-color: #ffffff;}
      .ExternalClass {width: 100%; background-color: #ffffff; }
      body {width: 100%; background-color: #ffffff; margin:0; padding:0; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;}
      html {width: 100%; }
      table {border-spacing: 0px;}
      p {margin-bottom: 0}

      @media only screen and (max-width: 640px)  {
      body[class=responsive] .deviceWidth {width:440px!important}
      body[class=responsive] .fichesannonces { width: 360px !important; }
      body[class=responsive] .deviceWidth2 {width:420px!important}
      }

      @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
      body[class=responsive] .deviceWidth {width:280px!important}
      body[class=responsive] .fichesannonces { width: 240px !important; }
      body[class=responsive] .deviceWidth2 {width:266px!important; padding: 0 0 3px 0!important;}
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body class="responsive">
    <table style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding: 10px 0;" valign="top" width="100%">
            <table class="deviceWidth" width="580" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <table class="deviceWidth2" style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="deviceWidth2" style="padding: 5px 15px 15px 15px; font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, Kalimati, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; color: #000000;" align="left">Bonjour,<br /><br />blablablablabla blablablablabla blablablablabla blablablablabla blablablablabla blablablablabla blablablablabla blablablablabla blablablablabla blablablablabla blablablablabla blablablablabla  :</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center">
                    <table class="fichesannonces" width="480" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000; text-align: center;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        <td width="480">
                            <table style="width: 116px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000; text-align: center;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="left">
                            <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table style="width: 106px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000; text-align: center;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" align="left">
                                <tr>
                                <td style="border: 1px solid gray;">
                                <a href="LIEN_VERS_LE_PROFIL"><img src="http://www.carrevert.net/IMG/carre.gif" alt="Voir la photo" width="100" style="border: 0; margin: 0; font-size: 14px; display: block;" /></a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td align="left" valign="top">
                                <a href="LIEN_VERS_LE_PROFIL" style="font-weight: bold; color: #dd0000; text-decoration: none;">Pseudopseudo</a><br /><span style="font-size: 11px; color: #595959;">26 ans<br /><span style="text-transform: capitalize;">ville</span></span>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td align="left">
                                <a href="LIEN_VERS_LE_PROFIL" style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: #0000ff;">Voir le profil</a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table style="width: 116px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000; text-align: center;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="left">
                            <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table style="width: 106px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000; text-align: center;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" align="left">
                                <tr>
                                <td style="border: 1px solid gray;">
                                <a href="LIEN_VERS_LE_PROFIL"><img src="http://www.carrevert.net/IMG/carre.gif" alt="Voir la photo" width="100" style="border: 0; margin: 0; font-size: 14px; display: block;" /></a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td align="left" valign="top">
                                <a href="LIEN_VERS_LE_PROFIL" style="font-weight: bold; color: #dd0000; text-decoration: none;">Pseudopseudo</a><br /><span style="font-size: 11px; color: #595959;">26 ans<br /><span style="text-transform : capitalize;">VILLE</span></span>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td align="left">
                                <a href="LIEN_VERS_LE_PROFIL" style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: #0000ff;">Voir le profil</a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table style="width: 116px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000; text-align: center;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="left">
                            <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table style="width: 106px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000; text-align: center;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" align="left">
                                <tr>
                                <td style="border: 1px solid gray;">
                                <a href="LIEN_VERS_LE_PROFIL"><img src="http://www.carrevert.net/IMG/carre.gif" alt="Voir la photo" width="100" style="border: 0; margin: 0; font-size: 14px; display: block;" /></a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td align="left" valign="top">
                                <a href="LIEN_VERS_LE_PROFIL" style="font-weight: bold; color: #dd0000; text-decoration: none;">onononnonon...</a><br /><span style="font-size: 11px; color: #595959;">26 ans<br /><span style="text-transform : capitalize;">VILLE</span></span>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td align="left">
                                <a href="LIEN_VERS_LE_PROFIL" style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: #0000ff;">Voir le profil</a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table style="width: 116px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000; text-align: center;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="left">
                            <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table style="width: 106px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000; text-align: center;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" align="left">
                                <tr>
                                <td style="border: 1px solid gray;">
                                <a href="LIEN_VERS_LE_PROFIL"><img src="http://www.carrevert.net/IMG/carre.gif" alt="Voir la photo" width="100" style="border: 0; margin: 0; font-size: 14px; display: block;" /></a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td align="left" valign="top">
                                <a href="LIEN_VERS_LE_PROFIL" style="font-weight: bold; color: #dd0000; text-decoration: none;">onononnonon...</a><br /><span style="font-size: 11px; color: #595959;">26 ans<br /><span style="text-transform : capitalize;">VILLE</span></span>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td align="left">
                                <a href="LIEN_VERS_LE_PROFIL" style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: #0000ff;">Voir le profil</a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table style="width: 116px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000; text-align: center;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="left">
                            <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table style="width: 106px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000; text-align: center;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" align="left">
                                <tr>
                                <td style="border: 1px solid gray;">
                                <a href="LIEN_VERS_LE_PROFIL"><img src="http://www.carrevert.net/IMG/carre.gif" alt="Voir la photo" width="100" style="border: 0; margin: 0; font-size: 14px; display: block;" /></a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td align="left" valign="top">
                                <a href="LIEN_VERS_LE_PROFIL" style="font-weight: bold; color: #dd0000; text-decoration: none;">onononnonon...</a><br /><span style="font-size: 11px; color: #595959;">26 ans<br /><span style="text-transform : capitalize;">VILLE</span></span>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td align="left">
                                <a href="LIEN_VERS_LE_PROFIL" style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: #0000ff;">Voir le profil</a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table style="width: 116px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000; text-align: center;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="left">
                            <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table style="width: 106px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000; text-align: center;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" align="left">
                                <tr>
                                <td style="border: 1px solid gray;">
                                <a href="LIEN_VERS_LE_PROFIL"><img src="http://www.carrevert.net/IMG/carre.gif" alt="Voir la photo" width="100" style="border: 0; margin: 0; font-size: 14px; display: block;" /></a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td align="left" valign="top">
                                <a href="LIEN_VERS_LE_PROFIL" style="font-weight: bold; color: #dd0000; text-decoration: none;">onononnonon...</a><br /><span style="font-size: 11px; color: #595959;">26 ans<br /><span style="text-transform : capitalize;">VILLE</span></span>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td align="left">
                                <a href="LIEN_VERS_LE_PROFIL" style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: #0000ff;">Voir le profil</a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table style="width: 116px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000; text-align: center;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="left">
                            <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table style="width: 106px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000; text-align: center;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" align="left">
                                <tr>
                                <td style="border: 1px solid gray;">
                                <a href="LIEN_VERS_LE_PROFIL"><img src="http://www.carrevert.net/IMG/carre.gif" alt="Voir la photo" width="100" style="border: 0; margin: 0; font-size: 14px; display: block;" /></a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td align="left" valign="top">
                                <a href="LIEN_VERS_LE_PROFIL" style="font-weight: bold; color: #dd0000; text-decoration: none;">onononnonon...</a><br /><span style="font-size: 11px; color: #595959;">26 ans<br /><span style="text-transform : capitalize;">VILLE</span></span>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td align="left">
                                <a href="LIEN_VERS_LE_PROFIL" style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: #0000ff;">Voir le profil</a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table style="width: 116px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000; text-align: center;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="left">
                            <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table style="width: 106px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000; text-align: center;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" align="left">
                                <tr>
                                <td style="border: 1px solid gray;">
                                <a href="LIEN_VERS_LE_PROFIL"><img src="http://www.carrevert.net/IMG/carre.gif" alt="Voir la photo" width="100" style="border: 0; margin: 0; font-size: 14px; display: block;" /></a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td align="left" valign="top">
                                <a href="LIEN_VERS_LE_PROFIL" style="font-weight: bold; color: #dd0000; text-decoration: none;">onononnonon...</a><br /><span style="font-size: 11px; color: #595959;">26 ans<br /><span style="text-transform : capitalize;">VILLE</span></span>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td align="left">
                                <a href="LIEN_VERS_LE_PROFIL" style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: #0000ff;">Voir le profil</a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For a start, as a general rule, stay away from `.class` in emails, stick to inline styles.

Comment: I only use them for responsive design or to overwrite outlook or yahoo's own CSS classes. You can notice that I also use a lot of inline styling :)

Comment: Also stay away from XHTML in emails.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not looking for general guidelines on how to build an e-mail. I have a very specific problem and I'd like to find a workaround to fix rendering issues despite common HTML sense.